# setState works perfectly when remote debugger is open but not when it's closed

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise

I need to decrypt  json data  using private key,the function works perfectly when remote debugger is open but when I stop it,it never gets resolved.

I've tried doing  it with async/await but nothing changed

```
decryptWithPrivateKey = (privateKey, encrypted) => {
    const buf = new Buffer(encrypted, "hex");
    encrypted = {
      iv: buf.toString("hex", 0, 16),
      ephemPublicKey: buf.toString("hex", 16, 49),
      mac: buf.toString("hex", 49, 81),
      ciphertext: buf.toString("hex", 81, buf.length)
    };
    // decompress publicKey
    encrypted.ephemPublicKey = publicKeyConvert(
      new Buffer(encrypted.ephemPublicKey, "hex"),
      false
    ).toString("hex");
    const twoStripped = privateKey.substring(2);
    const encryptedBuffer = {
      iv: new Buffer(encrypted.iv, "hex"),
      ephemPublicKey: new Buffer(encrypted.ephemPublicKey, "hex"),
      ciphertext: new Buffer(encrypted.ciphertext, "hex"),
      mac: new Buffer(encrypted.mac, "hex")
    };

    return decrypt(new Buffer(twoStripped, "hex"), 
    encryptedBuffer).then(
      decryptedBuffer => decryptedBuffer.toString()
    );
};
```

calling it like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            this.decryptWithPrivateKey(
              this.state.privateKey,
              this.state.ciphered
            ).then(result => {
              this.setState({ deciphered: result }, () => {
                console.log(this.state.deciphered);
                alert(this.state.deciphered);
              });
            });
          }}
        >
          <Text>decrypt</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

When pressing the button and remote debugger is open, it works perfectly. Once the debugger is closed, it does neither setState nor alert.

Comment: Does it behave the same with that `alert()` commented out?

Comment: Which library are you using for `Buffer`?

Comment: i'm using this one [https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer] @Asleepace

Comment: yes same result @Roamer-1888